# HP-Exstream String concatenating problems

Tags: string, concatenation, hp-exstream

I'm facing a problem when we try to concatenate to spinets into one.
There is a space between the two spinets, so the text ends missformated.

Has anyone see this problem, if yes, any clue on how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!
Bye.

Answer (score 0):

Using trim() function before concatenating the snippets will help remove the extra spaces.
If you are using variables to store the snippets, then the variable has in built property to trim the spaces i.e. the space before , after or in-between.

Comment: using RTRIM() will remove trailing spaces only